# Display data table in wpf chart

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, charts, highcharts

I've been searching for a way to display a data table inside a WPF chart, similar to the way excel chart does, but I can't find any answer.

I'm using System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting on WPF project and Visual Studio 2010.

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart Margin="12,22,15,46" Title="Chart">
<chartingToolkit:Chart.Series>
    <chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries IndependentValuePath="Key" DependentValuePath="Value" Title="Totals"/>
</chartingToolkit:Chart.Series>
```

What I want to achieve is my chart to look similar to this [example1](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_images/chart_data_table1.png) or even like this [example2](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_images/chart_data_table2.png).

If more information is needed,  please ask me for it.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: You can have a chart and display a datagrid below it

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to avoid that option if possible, but maybe I'll be doing that at the end.